# Send mail only if a file name has a specific pattern (_15_)

Tags: perl, email

The code below sends a mail for every file and moves the file to a different location. How can I mail files with only pattern `testfile_15_`? (Example : `testfile_15_stock`)
all the other files like (`testfile_13_stock` or `testfile_9_stock`) also need to move to a different location but without sending an email.

```
my @files =  grep { -f "$source_dir/$test_label/$_" } get_file_list("$source_dir/$test_label");
foreach my $file_name (@files)
{   
    mail_with_attachments("$source_dir/$test_label", $file_name );
    copy_mk_subdirs("$source_dir/$test_label/$file_name" , "$target_dir/$test_label", $glb_yr , $glb_month);
    log_it "Bestand $source_dir/$test_label/$file_name gekopieerd naar $target_dir/$test_label/$glb_yr/$glb_month .\n";
    l_move("$source_dir/$nco_label/$file_name" , "$hvr_dir/$file_name");             
    log_it "Bestand $source_dir/$test_label/$file_name verplaatst naar $hvr_dir .\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to check if the file contains the string `testfile_15_` to decide if you should send the email or not.  For example:

```
if ($file_name =~ /testfile_15_/) {
    mail_with_attachments("$source_dir/$test_label", $file_name );
}
```